# "Cannot read property '0' of null".Is it possible to find out the property name in the view where the error occurred?

Tags: vue.js

I often get this error during development, and I can’t find where it happened and with which variable:
*Cannot read property '0' of null*

```
<div id="vueApp" > ... {{probablyNotArray[0]}} ... </div>
```

How can i get the "probablyNotArray" name?
[image]

Comment: That could mean that `probablyNotArray` does not exist. could you show us the code where you define it`?

Answer (score 0):

You should see the code that causes the error on DevTool's sources tab, if you click (vue.js:11649)

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable an array? Are you accessing the data inside of a loop or are you referencing it directly to the template? In that case you would need to use:

```
{{ this.probablyNotArray[0] }}
```

Judging by the name of the array, do you need to carry out a check that the variable exists or that its an array?

```
{{ Array.isArray(probablyNotArray) ? probablyNotArray[0] : probablyNotArray }}
```

So instead of returning the index of the variable if its not an array, we return the variable.

Comment: @Василий Петрович did this solve your original question?